# Can I use "so that" or "such that" and "to"?

Tags: sentence-construction, prepositions

I wrote:

> ..., In this paper, we propose an XML scheme and a tool for converting these treebanks to XML. We designed the scheme **so/such that to facilitate** querying linguistic data using XQuery.

I know its probably wrong, but how can I use "so that" or "such that" here? To mean we designed the scheme (such) to facilitate .....

Comment: Sounds wrong.  You probably wanted to say "in order to" or just "to".

Comment: @VictorBazarov "in order to" or "to" indicates our aim of doing it, but doesn't convey how this aim affected the design process. right?

Comment: I don't pretend to understand the intricacies of XML, XQuery, etc.  It is unclear **what exactly** you are trying to convey.  In the paper you propose a scheme.  You also propose a tool.  The scheme is designed to be used with XQuery.  That's how I understand it.  Do you want it to be more elaborate?

Comment: Perhaps, "We designed the scheme to be suitable for using with XQuery for retrieving linguistic data"?

Comment: @VictorBazarov yes I mean that, just liked to know how to make such sentence with "so" or "such", if possible.

Comment: @VictorBazarov Suppose query in some scheme is difficult and in some is easier, then we designed the one that querying in a treebank with this scheme is easier

Comment: "We designed the scheme such that it can be used with XQuery..."

Answer (score 1):

"so" and "and such that" are totally unnecessary here.

Unless you're playing some sort of Buzzword Bingo, that is. In which case:

> We designed the scheme so/such that querying linguistic data using XQuery is facilitated.